# Video compression in react native using ffmpeg

Tags: react-native, ffmpeg, video-compression

I trying to compress video in react native using [react-native-ffmpeg](https://github.com/tanersener/react-native-ffmpeg) .

I am picking video using [react-native-image-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker).

I tried using command `-y -i ${inputVideo} -vcodec h264 -acodec mp3 ${finalVideo}`.

But it is failing with `rc:1`.
My code:-

```
 RNFFmpeg.execute(
            str_cmd,
        ).then(result => {
             if (result.rc === 0) {
                 console.log("successfully compressed");
             } else {
                 console.log("error",result);
             }
          });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you have to include the input video into the directory for your app.

You should be able to do so with [`react-native-fs`](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs).

And [here is the relevant code](https://github.com/tanersener/react-native-ffmpeg-test/blob/60aa6cd991375c8c12827cb5f19b4f6ce2868768/src/video-util.js#L53) from the `react-native-ffmeg` example project.